# custom push segue animation

Tags: ios, swift, segue

hello I want to have the push segue default animation while Presenting View Controller. 
I have three controllers In my storyBoard. FirstController is attached to the navigationController. first controller and second is connected through segue as `present Modally`. I am launching the third controller from second controller like this

```
let takeProductPhotoController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("takeProductPhotoController") as! TakeProductPhotoController
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: takeProductPhotoController )
            self.presentViewController(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

The problem is ThirdController is popping up like modally I mean from the bottom which I don't want. I want to have a animation like push segue

I think It will work If I do `self.pushViewController` but pushViewController is not in this self

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated:true)
```